# no, not, non, which is correct for an adjective?

Tags: word-choice, no-not

I'm writing a tag for pronouns that are not personal. In that context, which is more correct or more frequently used?

- non-personal
- non personal
- not personal

Comment: That would be: impersonal pronouns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Non-](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/non):***

> - used to add the meaning "not" or "the opposite of" to adjectives and nouns:
>
>   - *non-sexist*
>   - *non-racist*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

***Non-personal*** is the more common idiomatic  usage, see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=non-personal%2Cnon%20personal&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnon%20-%20personal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnon%20personal%3B%2Cc0)